# Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms in, Node.js, MongooseError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am busy creating a project which allows the user to enter "Email" & "Password" to register to the site,

When I try to enter a user using the "Email" & "Password" to enter this site, I get the following error:

> MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after
> 10000ms
>
> Unhandled rejection MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() buffering
> timed out after 10000ms

I have tried all the proposed solutions I found here which have a similar problem, delete the *node_modules* folder and reinstall mongoose.

Please see my code below, thanks!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded ({extended: true}));

mongoose.connect = ("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const userSchema = {
  email: String,
  password: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("home")
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
res.render("login")
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
res.render("register")
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
const newUser = new User({
  email: req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
  });
  newUser.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("secrets");
   }
 });
});
```

Can anyone help me out?

[Atom images - Project SecretsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB0rK.png)

Comment: Please provide the controller code

Comment: Please see code above, I dont seem to see where  my error is. thanks

Comment: In your own words, what is the line `mongoose.connect = (...)` doing?

Comment: I hope i have this correct and clear enough, but mongoose.connect = (...), what is should do is connect to my localhost server?  but when i start the server on port 3000 and navigate to the register screen, insert the details required, I get the error: MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms

Unhandled rejection MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: Your internet connection is probably not strong enough to initiate and hold a database connection. That was my experience.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!

Comment: Try swapping localhost for 127.0.0.1. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

try adding one more line under mongoose.connect curly braces:-

```
mongoose.connect("monogodb://localhost....",{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('successfully connected');
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('not connected');
})
```

you can check the error in console if not connected by replacing "not connected" with 'e'

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, Make sure that your mongoDB database username and password is alphanumeric with no special symbols. And dont add this:

```
{useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex:true})
```

simply write this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,).then(()=>{
    console.log(`successfully connected`);
    }).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(`not connected`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/student-reg').then(() => {
  console.log(`successfully connected`);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(`not connected`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html), if the connection fails on your machine, try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in this line of code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Answer (score -1):

For a reason my IP address changed, so I had to update it inside Mongo DB - NetworkAccess - Edit - Use the new IP address, maybe you'll see a button to update with current Ip or something like that, click it

Answer (score -2):

try this one :

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          email: String,
          password: String
    });
    
    mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
    
    const User = mongoose.model("User");

///////

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
const newUser = new User({
  email: req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
  });
  newUser.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("secrets");
   }
 });
});
```