# I get MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms--- what is the solution (my (IP) in allow anywhere)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my node.js code

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://ab1:0000@ahmed.gqxyt3n.mongodb.net/ab.ac?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", () => console.log("Error in Connecting to Database"));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to Database"));

app.post("/sign_up", (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var phno = req.body.phno;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phno: phno,
        password: password,
    };

    db.collection("users").insertOne(data, (err, collection) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("Record Inserted Successfully");
    });

    return res.redirect("signup_success.html");
});

app
    .get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.set({
            "Allow-access-Allow-Origin": "*",
        });
        return res.redirect("index.html");
    })
    .listen(3000);

console.log("Listening on PORT 3000");
```

and my terminal output

```
PS C: \Users\ dream\ Desktop\ indea pro db > nodemon index.js[nodemon] 2.0 .19[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon] watching path(s): * .*[nodemon] watching extensions: js, mjs, json[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening on PORT 3000
C: \Users\ dream\ Desktop\ indea pro db\ index.js: 43
throw err; ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()`
buffering timed out after 10000 ms
at Timeout. < anonymous > (C: \Users\ dream\ Desktop\ indea pro db\ node_modules\ mongoose\ lib\ drivers\ node - mongodb - native\ collection.js: 151: 23)
at listOnTimeout(node: internal / timers: 559: 17)
at processTimers(node: internal / timers: 502: 7)[nodemon] app crashed - waiting
for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: are you using MondoDB Atlas ?

Comment: did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652518/operation-users-insertone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-in-node-js-mon

Comment: @kedarsedai     yes am use MondoDB Atlas , pleas I need help with error I spend 3 day try to fix the error

Comment: @Rihabsabri     am try it but don't work for me